# Formatting floats so they all have the same total digits (ex 1.234, 456.7)

Tags: python-2.7

I'm looking to format numbers so they always show only 5 digits total.
So that 1.234567 and 987.6543 and 12345.678 would look like:
1.2345
987.65
12345

I know the numbers are never higher than 5 digits on the left side.
Regards,T

Comment: Should `1.234567` be rounded to `1.2346`? Because your example doesn't indicate so (depending on your rounding convention perhaps).

Comment: doesn't do the trick actually. You're correct the first one should round to 1.2346.

Comment: With the above trick (`"{:.5g}".format(x)`, I can get 1.2346, 987.65 and 12346. That seems to do what you want.

Comment: my bad your latest actually does the trick.